# JSF 2 Lifecycle

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, getter

I have this code for BookModel.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "BookModel.findBookTitle", query = "SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'no', m.title, m.author, REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.content, ' ', 30), '<br>', ' '), m.viewed, m.hashid FROM book m, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE m.title like 'a%'")
public class BookModel implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_SEQ_GEN")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;
}
```

And BookService.java for the business layer:

```
@Stateless
public class BookService
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<BookModel> getBook() {
       Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("BookModel.findBookTitle");
       List<BookModel> result = query.getResultList();
       return result;
    }
 }
```

And BookBean.java for the presentation layer:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "BookBean")
@RequestScoped
public class BookBean implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private BookService bookService;
    private DataModel<BookModel> book;

    public DataModel<BookModel> getBook() {
       return book;
    }
}
```

And the page book.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <p:dataTable id="bookList" value="#{BookBean.book}" var="book">
    ...
    </p:dataTable> 
 </html>
```

My question is: How can I restrict the method **getBook()** in **BookBean** to be executed only once instead of six times - presumably for each phase of JSF lifecycle. Has anyone else come across this before? Please help. Have been stuck on this for the last day without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. It should usually not harm. Getters are solely there to provide access points to bean properties, not to do some business jobs.

If you did call the `@EJB`s `getBook()` method inside that managed bean method like follows

```
public DataModel<BookModel> getBook() {
   return new ListDataModel<BookModel>(bookService.getBook());
}
```

then this is indeed going to be expensive as it would call the DB that much times as the getter is called. You would like to do the job in the bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` instead.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    book = new ListDataModel<BookModel>(bookService.getBook());
}
```

#### See also:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, the method name `getBook()` and variable name `book` is not really self-documenting since it *actually* contains more than one book. I'd use `getBooks()` and `books` instead.

Comment: I have changed the method name to `getBooks()` and only have `return this.book;` and the method executed only once. You're a genius, man! Thanks heap. Guess I have to hit the books and the JEE 6 online tutorial again to prevent making this sort of mistake in the future.